# How do I get the results with the root resolved in python?

Tags: python, sympy, numeric

How do I get the results with the root resolved.

```
a = Eq(x**3 + x**2 - 3*x + 1,0)

b = solve(a)

print(b)
```

results:

```
[1, -1 + sqrt(2), -sqrt(2) - 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `evalf`:

```
In [4]: [s.evalf() for s in b]                                                                                                                 
Out[4]: [1.0, 0.414213562373095, -2.41421356237309]
```